# Save complex object outside foreach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

i am trying to store a complex object in database. There are a lot of relationships like one-to-one and one-to-many. Everything works fine but at the moment i am doing the saving inside the foreach loop, which is not correct.

```
foreach($list as $item){

$objA = new ObjA();
$objA->id = $item['id'];
$objA->save();

$objB = new ObjB();
$objB->name = $item['key']['name'];

$objA->extra()->save($objB);

foreach ($item['data']['products'] as $pr) {
    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = $pr['name'];
    $objA->products()->save($product);
}

}
```

This is the code atm, but i need to execute the query outside the foreach.
How can i achieve this?
products and extra methods are something like that :

```
    public function extra(){
        return $this->hasOne(ObjB::class);
    }
```

Comment: In the provided souce, you're using $product as loop's value THEN as new instance of Product class. So the loop's value is overwritten.

Comment: Moreover, for now i did something like 
$final_array = array(); <- before foreach

array_push($final_array , $objA->toArray()); <- after $objA->id = $item['id'];
and finally outside the foreach
ObjA::insert($final_array );

But the problem is the relationships exist

Comment: @Armage, thanks for your comment, i fixed it! But, my problem is not that it is not working! It works, i am searching for a way to do a proper refactor in order not to call  the save method inside the for-each loop. 
I need somehow gather everything, and outside the for-each make something like
MyClass::insert($allthedata)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many iterations you have, it might be ok the way you do it. Otherwise, if you want a more fluent solution, here it is:

```
 $_products = [];
    foreach ($item['data']['products'] as $index=>$product) {
        $_products[$index]['name'] = $product['name'];
//      $product = new Product();
//      $product->name = $product['name'];
//      $objA->products()->save($product);
    }
 
 $objA->products()->insert($data);
```

This is a " bulk insert ". Meaning that you gather many arrays of data in an array, pass it to insert and Eloquent will compose a long query and execute it at once.

Comment: You mean : insert($products), isn't it ?